# algebraic determination of the correct phase angle

Tags: trigonometry

Let's solve $A\sin x+B\cos x=C$. We know $A\sin x+B\cos x=R\sin(x+k)$ and we easily calculate $R = \sqrt{(A^2 +B^2)}$. We calculate angle $k$ to be the $\arctan(B/A)$. We get a result from the calculator, let's say $m$. We know that $k=180n+m$, where $n$ is an integer. The question is which of the whole number of $180n+m$ degrees values is the appropriate for phase angle $k$? The $m$? The $180+m$? The $360+m$? Which?

I have been told that we need to take into account the signs of $B$ and $A$, which will tell us in which quadrant the $k$ is, so we will calculate appropriately. My question is, isn't there an algebraic way to determine which $k$ value we need out of the total $180n+m$ values? I don't know, but I don't feel I am solving mathematically enough, when I consider the signs of the $A$, $B$, in order to determine the $k$ value! Can you understand me?

Comment: I totally understand your misery. This will help you:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2

Comment: why atan returns wrong results and we need atan2? in other equations I use atan only without having to bother for atan2. why in this situation I need atan2?

Comment: It is because in the derivation of formula $\arctan(B/A)$, the non-injective tangens function was employed and so quadrant-information is lost and the inverse function (arctan) cannot make up for it. You can compare it to an equation $a^2 = 1$ containing the non-injective square function, where you cannot tell whether $a=1$ or $a=-1$ without additional information. That additional information could e.g. be knowledge about $a$ being a physical quantity that is always positive. In your case that additional information is provided by the signs of $A$ and $B$.